# Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with user-defined table type

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures

I'm new here and I'm facing a trouble currently, my scenario is that I wanted to insert and update data from Excel into a SQL Server table.

For the insert part it works perfectly but when it comes to update I have no idea how should I do that. I have search for few methods and I found this is the most comfortable for me by using stored procedure.

Here is my code that I'm using now. When I try it gave me this error:

> Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with user-defined table type

```
--- Stored procedure ---
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[chkUpdate]
    @Operator IC_CHK READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    set nocount on;

    MERGE INTO tb_Operator c1
    USING @Operator c2 ON c1.IC = c2.IC

    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET
            c1.Name = c2.Name,
            --c1.IC = c2.IC,
            c1.Email = c2.Email,
            c1.Status = c2.Status,
            c1.Datetime = c2.Datetime

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT VALUES(c2.Name, c2.IC, c2.Email, c2.[Status], c2.[Datetime]);
end

--- User-defined table type ---
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IC_CHK] as table 
(
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [IC] [bigint] NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](MAX) NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Datetime] [datetime] NULL
)
```

VS 2010 code:

```
protected void btnImport_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;

    try
    {
        string path = string.Concat(Server.MapPath("~/Excel/" + UploadExcel.FileName));
        UploadExcel.SaveAs(path);

        String strCon = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;",path);
        OleDbDataAdapter myda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]", strCon);

        DataTable myds = new DataTable();
        myda.Fill(myds);

        for (i = 0; i <= myds.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            String constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("chkUpdate"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = con;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Operator", path);

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        MsgBox1.alert("Import success");
        View.Visible = true;

        vBinds();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MsgBox1.alert(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Do check for me and I'm appreciate it. Thank you

P/S: I double confirm that my user-defined table type has the same data type with my table.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: You load your data into a `DataTable` which is the right thing to do if you want to pass a table-valued parameter. Then you ignore it and instead pass the string *path* to where the data originated, rather than passing your `DateTable` object in.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks i just noticed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `INSERT` in your `MERGE` statement, I would recommend to **explicitly** define the columns you're inserting into. Most likely, that's the cause of the error - you're inserting your columns - but you're not specifying **which** target columns those should be inserted into.

Since you're **not** specifying that, you must supply values for **each column** in the table, in the **exact order** in which they are defined - is that really the case?? E.g. what do you insert into your `ID` column in the table??

Assuming the `ID` column on your actual database table is an `IDENTITY` column, I would use (otherwise, you'd have to list `ID` in the list of columns to insert into as well and provide a value in the `VALUES` list of values):

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT(Name, IC, Email, [Status], [DateTime])
  VALUES(c2.Name, c2.IC, c2.Email, c2.[Status], c2.[Datetime]);
```

and I would *also recommend* not to use T-SQL reserved keywords like `status` or `datetime` as your **column names** - you're just asking for trouble doing so. Use **more expressive** names - something that really relates to your business domain - not just `datetime`.....

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and I've fixed the error. I'll go for my own on the error just discovered ;)